# Can't upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1.554 B]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1.341 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Fetched 1.343 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/focal", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2089, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1860, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.prepare():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 431, in prepare
    self.openCache()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 214, in openCache
    return self._openCache(lock)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 242, in _openCache
    lock)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.linux_metapackage = self.quirks._get_linux_metapackage(self, False)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 845, in _get_linux_metapackage
    source = pkg.candidate.record['Source']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'record'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 497, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 450, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/focal", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2089, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1860, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.prepare():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 431, in prepare
    self.openCache()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 214, in openCache
    return self._openCache(lock)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 242, in _openCache
    lock)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.linux_metapackage = self.quirks._get_linux_metapackage(self, False)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-zu_wjdn5/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 845, in _get_linux_metapackage
    source = pkg.candidate.record['Source']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'record'
```

Any thoughts here?

Best regards!

Comment: to be honest I'd try to upgrade the intermediate steps.. For example from 18.04 to 18.10 and then from 18.10 to 19.04 and so on.. or better make a new install from 20.04

Comment: This looks like a possible Locale issue to me. Please edit your question to include the complete output of the command `locale`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do:

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

before you did that? I remember reading about needing to have the latest updates installed before attempting a release upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try a lot of option, but cleaning all the apt sources lists,resetting the locale and changing the version of the installed Python to the original version of Ubuntu 18.05 (3.6) works fine and I finally could upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.